# Unable to display text from database in a text widget in Flutter

Tags: sql, flutter, dart, gridview, sqflite

Been coding in dart for a few months now. Currently trying to generate a grid view that contains titles from a a local SQL database. I am able to go through the database and save the titles to an array for later use. I am able to print them out no problem but when I try to display them in my grid view I get "type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'String'" The weird thing is my code worked for a second and displayed the information properly but as soon as I refreshed the page (I did not touch the code) I got the error which is confusing me the most.

Database Helper class

```
getFactTitle(String target, int position) async {
    Database db = await this.database;
    String searchString =
        ('SELECT title FROM factTable WHERE fid="' + target + '"');
    var result = await db.rawQuery(searchString);
    if (result.length > 0) {
      titles[position] = result.first.values.first.toString();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
    
  }
```

Grid View

```
Widget _buttons() {
    return Expanded(
      child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2, //NUMBER OF COLUMNS
        children: List.generate(numberOfFacts, (index) {
          return Center(
            child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                  icon: Image.asset('assets/pictures/' +
                      category +
                      _stringIndex(index) +
                      'a.jpg'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print("Clicked: " + category + _stringIndex(index));
                  }),
              Text(
                _getTitle(index),
              ),
            ]),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }

  _getTitle(int index) async {
    print(titles[index]);
    return titles[index];
  }

  _getTitles() async {
    String theTitle;
    _getCategory();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfFacts; i++) {
      String target = category + (i.toString());
      await helper.getFactTitle(target, i);
      print(titles[i]);
      theTitle = titles[i];
    }
    return theTitle;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `_getTitle(int index)` is `async` you'll have to wait for it to complete.
In this case you can use a `FutureBuilder`.

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: _getTitle(index),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text(snapshot.data);
        }
     }
);
```

you could also handle error and waiting state.

More info: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: Thank you! I got it!

Answer (score 0):

`_getTitle(int index)` should not be `async`.